# How to take blank value in the variable in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep

I have taken 2 variables in the `grep` command for search in the file. User is only putting one and pressing enter on the second variable, its throwing the error.

I want to set empty value on the variable second if user doesn't enter anything for the second one.

```
#!/bin/bash 
find /var/log/nginx/ -type f ( -iname "access.log*" ! -iname "access.log*.gz" ) -exec cat {} + >> output.txt 
echo enter the file name read file1 
echo "enter varible 1" 
read var1 
echo "enter varible 2" 
read var2 
grep -w $var1 output.txt | grep $var2 | cut -d' ' -f1,4,12,25 > $file1 
grep -w $var1 output.txt | grep $var2 |sed 's#.*(aff_id=[[:digit:]]\+).*(off_id=[[:digit:]]‌​\+).*(trans_‌​id=[[:alnum:]]\+)‌​;.*#\1 \2 \3#' > out2.txt 
paste -d' ' $file1 out2.txt > out3.txt 
rm -rf output.txt 
rm -rf $file1
```

Comment: Please include examples

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant data and commands that you are using, along with any error messages or warnings that you may get.

Comment: this is the script... if i dont put varible 2 value and simply press enter. it is through error

Comment: The good practice is to add it in question, not as comment. Please check my edit

Comment: By "does not enter anything" do you mean "only presses enter" or "doesn't even press enter"?

Comment: No, its not even taking enter.

Comment: if someone want to search the file with one variable only and doesn't want to enter the value of second variable, by pressing simply enter and then the script will works

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you might be looking for is the ability to test for whether or not a variable was assigned a value. This can be done using Bash string-comparison operators. These operators are documented in several different common references, e.g.:

- [Bash Guide for Beginners: Chapter 7 - Conditional Statements](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Section 7.3 - Other Comparison Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

In particular, you can use the `if [ -n "${string}" ]` to test for non-null strings. Adapting your script to use this test might result in something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/log/nginx/ -type f ( -iname "access.log*" ! -iname "access.log*.gz" ) -exec cat {} + >> output.txt
echo enter the file name read file1
echo "enter varible 1"
read var1
echo "enter varible 2"
read var2

if [[ -n "${var2}" ]]; then var2=""; fi

grep -w $var1 output.txt | grep $var2 | cut -d' ' -f1,4,12,25 > $file1
grep -w $var1 output.txt | grep $var2 | sed 's#.*(aff_id=[[:digit:]]\+).*(off_id=[[:digit:]]‌​\+).*(trans_‌​id=[[:alnum:]]\+)‌​;.*#\1 \2 \3#' > out2.txt

paste -d' ' $file1 out2.txt > out3.txt
rm -rf output.txt
rm -rf $file1
```

That said, I don't think that will help solve your problem. To avoid your `grep` errors it should suffice to quote the variables, e.g. `grep -w "${var1}" output.txt`. Here is what your script looks like with quoted variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/log/nginx/ -type f ( -iname "access.log*" ! -iname "access.log*.gz" ) -exec cat {} + >> output.txt
echo enter the file name read file1
echo "enter varible 1"
read var1
echo "enter varible 2"
read var2

if [[ -n "${var2}" ]];
    var2=""
fi

grep -w "${var1}" output.txt | grep "${var2}" | cut -d' ' -f1,4,12,25 > $file1
grep -w "${var1}" output.txt | grep "${var2}" | sed 's#.*(aff_id=[[:digit:]]\+).*(off_id=[[:digit:]]‌​\+).*(trans_‌​id=[[:alnum:]]\+)‌​;.*#\1 \2 \3#' > out2.txt

paste -d' ' $file1 out2.txt > out3.txt
rm -rf output.txt
rm -rf $file1
```

An explanation for why you need to quote the variables in your `grep` expressions can be found in the [Bash Guide for Beginners: Section 3.4.8 - Word Splitting](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html):

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting. [...] Explicit null arguments ("""" or "''") are retained. Unquoted implicit null arguments, resulting from the expansion of parameters that have no values, are removed. If a parameter with no value is expanded within double quotes, a null argument results and is retained.

Comment: Any comment on the line saying `echo enter the file name read file1` and what this means for `$file1` later in the code?